# ProductScreen undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need help. I can't access or view my `ProductScreen` to get the product details and when I hover over the productScreen in the route or anywhere it tells me undefined. I hope someone can help me out here.

Also anytime I try resolving I get error in the console saying

```js
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "image")
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { detailsProduct } from "../actions/productActions";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ProductScreen(props) {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { product, loading, error } = productDetails;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    if (props.history && props.match) {
      props.history.push("/cart/" + props.match.params.id + "?qty=" + qty);
    }
  };
  if (!product) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="back-to-result">
          <Link to="/">Back to result</Link>
        </div>
        {loading ? (
          <div>loading...</div>
        ) : error ? (
          <div>{error}</div>
        ) : (
          <div className="details">
            <div className="details-image">
              {<img src={product.image} alt="product"></img>}
            </div>
            <div className="details-info">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <h4>{product.name}</h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)
                </li>
                <li>
                  Price: <b>${product.price}</b>
                </li>
                <li>
                  Description:
                  <div>{product.description}</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="details-action">
              <ul>
                <li>Price: {product.price}</li>
                <li>
                  Status:{product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of"}
                </li>
                <li>
                  Qty:{" "}
                  <select
                    value={qty}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setQty(e.target.value);
                    }}
                  >
                    {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                      <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                        {" "}
                        {x + 1}{" "}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                    <button
                      onClick={handleAddToCart}
                      className="button primary"
                    >
                      {" "}
                      Add to cart
                    </button>
                  )}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        )};
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import CartScreen from "./screens/CartScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen";

function App() {
  const openMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.add("open");
  };
  const closeMenu = () => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.remove("open");
  };
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="grid-container">
        ...
        <main className="main">
          <div className="content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
              <Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartScreen />} />
              <Route path="/" exact={true} element={<HomeScreen />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </main>
        <footer className="footer">All right reserved.</footer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

ProductAction

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.massage });
  }
};

const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/product/" + productId);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.massage });
  }
};
export { listProducts, detailsProduct };
```

I need a solution or even a clue i can work with